# How to replace variable value with its absolute path in file?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I Want to search variable and replace with its absolute path in file.

```
setenv ABC /home/xyz
cat file.txt
${ABC}/Test/Folder_1
${ABC}/Test/Folder_2
```

I want to replace all occurance of the ${ABC} by /home/xyz.
I tried by the below mentioned way, but does not work,

```
sed -i 's/\$ABC/echo $ABC/g' file.txt
```

I can do by below mentioned way, but I do not want to do this way.(I have to put so many back slash)

```
$ echo $ABC | sed -i 's/\$ABC/\/home\/xyz/g' file.txt
```

Please give me some suggestion for this question.

Thank You.

Comment: `setenv` is not a `bash` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the value from a variable in your replacement string, you could use

```
sed "s#\${ABC}#$ABC#g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Character after `s` in `sed` is the delimiter and it can be any one character of your choice and it works as long as it's not in the `string-to-be-matched` and `string-to-be-replaced`.

Example :

`sed 's:string-to-be-matched:string-to-be-replaced:g' file-to-be-edited`

`:` is the delimiter

`g` means global replacement.

---

In your case, as the `string-to-be-replaced` contains the `/` , the same you are using as sed delimiter.

Simple Solution will be :

```
sed -i 's:${ABC}:'"$ABC"':g' fill.txt
```

`'"` is at either end of $ABC in the replacement string. Purpose is to expand shell variable to use with `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the absolute path is `readlink -f ${ABC}/Test/Folder_2`

Or the perl alternative to your slash hungry command

```
$ echo $ABC | sed -i 's/\$ABC/\/home\/xyz/g' file.txt
```

would be

```
$ echo $ABC | perl -p -i -e 's!\$ABC!/home/xyz!g'
```

the first character after the `'s` above will be used as the delimiter in the replacement expression (i.e. `'s@foo@bar@g'`)